# Is there a "sweep style" iPhone app that mimics the new Sony compact camera technique?

Tags: panorama, iphone

I love capturing panoramas on my iPhone and for this, I use Autostitch Panorama. But does anyone know of a "sweep style" App for the iPhone that mimics the technique used in the new compact Sony cameras? This would be a great App to have if it was effective.

Comment: Mark, you do a great job in proving the point that "the best camera is the one the you have with you"

Answer (score 7):

This feature is now built in to the new iPhone 5, and is also available on the iPhone 4S (if you have updated to iOS6).

The same feature is also built into Android devices with the (little known) panoramic feature.

Camera > Settings > Shooting Mode > Panorama

Short video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txwdD11sW1s

Answer (score 6):

There are two apps that are both seem to be well-liked that provide the pan/sweep functionality you desire.

[360 Panorama](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/360-panorama/id377342622) (by Occipital - currently $1.99)

[Photosynth](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photosynth/id430065256?mt=8) (by Microsoft - currently free)

Both apps allow you to look at the phone's screen, pan/sweep the camera to record, and the app will stitch together a panoramic image based on the area you captured.

Comment: You should add that the feature is now part of iOS 6, so it's built-in.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar for my Android phone and I came across this in the Google search, maybe this is what you are after?

[VideoPano](http://www.jefframos.com/2010/01/review-videopano-for-the-iphone/) makes panoramic images straight from videos!

Comment: Thanks for that; interesting.

Pity the reviews all say that the image size and quality fall way behind the dedicated still image stitching Apps.

There's an App' opportunity here I think ...

Answer (score 2):

There is a new app called [You Gotta See This!](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/you-gotta-see-this/id379058646?mt=8) that seems to be just what you are looking for. However, it is only available for the iPhone 4, because it uses the internal gyroscope to  determine the direction so that it can stitch the photo correctly.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm a 3GS user, so I won't be able to make use of the App, sadly, but here must be an opportunity for a great solution to capturing sweep-style panoramics on all iPhones. For now though, I'll keep using AutoStitch:
http://www.iphonebroadcast.co.uk/?tag=autostitch-panorama